# how to get specific element's value from a large XML

Tags: java, xml, sax

I am a beginner in `JAVA SAX`. I have a large `XML` file and I want to extract some information from it. below is the `XML` file, what I want to extract and the code:

Extract from the `XML` file:

```
    ...
    <Synset baseConcept="3" id="mizaAj_n2AR">
          <SynsetRelations>
            <SynsetRelation relType="hyponym" targets="TaboE_n2AR"/>
            <SynsetRelation relType="hyponym" targets="TaboE_n2AR"/>
            <SynsetRelation relType="hypernym" targets="ragobap_n4AR"/>
            <SynsetRelation relType="hypernym" targets="ragobap_n4AR"/>
            <SynsetRelation relType="hypernym" targets="Tiybap_Aln~afos_n1AR"/>
            <SynsetRelation relType="hypernym" targets="Tiybap_Aln~afos_n1AR"/>
          </SynsetRelations>
          <MonolingualExternalRefs>
            <MonolingualExternalRef externalReference="04623612-n" externalSystem="PWN30"/>
          </MonolingualExternalRefs>
        </Synset>
        <Synset baseConcept="3" id="ragobap_n4AR">
          <SynsetRelations>
            <SynsetRelation relType="antonym" targets="mizaAj_n2AR"/>
            <SynsetRelation relType="antonym" targets="mizaAj_n2AR"/>
          </SynsetRelations>
          <MonolingualExternalRefs>
            <MonolingualExternalRef externalReference="04624826-n" externalSystem="PWN30"/>
          </MonolingualExternalRefs>
        </Synset>
        <Synset baseConcept="3" id="tasal~uT_n1AR">
          <SynsetRelations>
            <SynsetRelation relType="has_instance" targets="simap_n1AR"/>
            <SynsetRelation relType="is_instance" targets="simap_n1AR"/>
          </SynsetRelations>
          <MonolingualExternalRefs>
            <MonolingualExternalRef externalReference="04625882-n" externalSystem="PWN30"/>
          </MonolingualExternalRefs>
        </Synset>
...
```

I want:

```
hyponym: 2
hypernym: 4
antonym: 2 
has_instance: 1
is_instance:1
```

The code (the main class and my handler):

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
    import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
    import org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory;

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException{

            XMLReader p = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
            p.setContentHandler(new handler());
            p.parse("test1.xml");
}
   ----------------------------------------
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

    public class handler extends DefaultHandler {

        @Override
        public void startElement(String SpacenameURI, String localName,
                String qName, Attributes attrs) {

            System.out.println("qname = " + qName);
            String node = qName;

            if (attrs != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < attrs.getLength(); i++) {
                    //nous récupérons le nom de l'attribut
                    String aname = attrs.getLocalName(i);
                    //Et nous affichons sa valeur
                    System.out.println("Attribut " + aname + " valeur : " + attrs.getValue(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I did mention what I want. I want to get some information from the XML file. My code don't get me the right information.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you don't want the values but you'd like to count the occurrences of some specific elements in the file. Do you want the counts per Synset element or just over the entire file in general?

Comment: Yes, but not exactly what I want because the amount of the information in the XML file, I didn't put it all. brief, what I want is to parse all the file then the programme gives me all the value of the attribute 'relType' that existed in the file and count their occurrences.

Comment: Then add a `Map<String, Integer>` to your handler class where the keys are the attribute values and the values are number of occurrences.

Comment: Any solution would be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Map<String, Integer> countElements(File xmlFile) {

    Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();

    try {
        XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(xmlFile);
        XMLStreamReader reader = inputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(fileInputStream);

        while(reader.hasNext()) {
            reader.next();
            if(reader.isStartElement() && reader.getLocalName().equals("SynsetRelation")) {
                String relTypeValue = reader.getAttributeValue("", "relType");

                if(!counts.containsKey(relTypeValue)) {
                    counts.put(relTypeValue, 0);
                }

                counts.put(relTypeValue, counts.get(relTypeValue) + 1);
            }
        }

        fileInputStream.close();
    } catch (XMLStreamException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return counts;
}
```

This code uses a Stream reader, meaning it will only load one element at a time in memory. This makes it efficient, even for large files.

A map is used to keep track of the counts. Every time I encounter a "SynsetRelation" element I check first to see if it is already counted, then I increment the counter.

The result is map containing the counts per detected value.

You would use it like this in your main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> results = countElements(new File("your file location here.xml"));
    }  
}
```

Comment: thanks man, but can you comment the code so I can understand it and modify it according to needs .. Again tanks ;)

Comment: You're welcome. I provided some additional text below the code to clarify it. If there are specific parts you're confused about, ask away!

Comment: I have added a usage example at the bottom of my answer, you should just add the countElements method as a private static method to the main class or create another new class that has the method in it and then call that. (like new XmlCounter().countElements();)

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I did but now I want to add you code ti my handle class (startElement method) what should I do??

Comment: My answer replaces the code you had, it's a different approach and does not use the handler class.

Comment: I figured it out myself. I have to change the whole code if I want it in the handler class. Anyway thank you and wish you the best.